# Creating a "min" function in R

Tags: r, function

A friend of mine recently took a midterm in which the first problem asked him to create his own "baby.min()" function in R without utilizing "sort()" or "min()". This function was to operate in the same way as "min()". That is, min(x) returns the minimum value in some vector x.

I'm fairly new to programming and thus came up with a seemingly overly-complicated solution; however, I was wondering how succinct a function this really could be.

For reference, my idea for the function is as follows:

```
baby.min <- function(x){
  if (length(x) == 0) {
    return(Inf)
  } else {
    counter <- 0
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
      for (j in 1:length(x) & j != i){
        if (x[i] <= x[j]) {
          counter <- counter + 1
        } else {
          break
          counter <- 0
        }
      }
    if (counter == length(x) - 1){
      return(x[i])
    }
    }
  }
}
```

(Again, I understand this is probably a poor solution; I'm simply interested in seeing different ways in which better programmers than myself might solve it.)

Answer (score 4):

```
baby.min <- function(x) {
  my_min = Inf
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (x[i] < my_min) my_min = x[i]
  }
  return(my_min)
}

baby.min(1:10)
# [1] 1

baby.min(integer(0))
# [1] Inf

x = rnorm(100)
identical(min(x), baby.min(x))
# [1] TRUE
```

Just for @bouncyball, with `na.rm` option:

```
baby.min <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  if (na.rm) {
    x = na.omit(x)
  } else {
    if (anyNA(x)) return(NA)
  }
  my_min = Inf
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (x[i] < my_min) my_min = x[i]
  }
  return(my_min)
}
```

Though, if you want to get around the  "do not use `sort()` or `min()`", but get a little clever, you could do something like these ;)

```
baby.min2 = function(x, ...) -max(-x, ...) # also handles na.rm
baby.min3 = function(x) x[order(x)][1]
baby.min4 = function(x) x[which.min(x)]
```

Comment: Really interesting - thank you! Definitely more succinct than my idea...

Answer (score 2):

Solution in R that works *exactly* like min():

```
BabyMin <- function(vector){    
  min <- Inf    
  if (length(vector)==0){
    # write(paste0("Warning message:\n",    
    #              "no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf"), stderr())
    warning("no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf", call.=F)    
  } else if (any(is.na(vector))){ 
    return(NA)    
  } else {    
    for (n in 1:length(vector)){    
      value <- vector[n]    
      if (value < min){    
        min <- value    
      }    
    }     
  }    
  return(min)    
}    

a <- c(4,2,3,1,7,8,9,12)    
BabyMin(a)    
# [1] 1    

b <- NULL    
BabyMin(b)    
# Warning message:    
# no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf    
# [1] Inf    

c <- c(NA, rnorm(2))    
BabyMin(c)    
# [1] NA
```

Comment: Instead of `write` you could use `warning`, which would give a standard way of doing the same, with the added benefit of enabling `?warnings`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `r`, but here is how I would plan the function.

```
FUNCTION min (ARRAY x)
    IS x INVALID?
    THEN EXIT WITH ERROR

    INSTANTIATE min_x AS OBJECT LIKE IN x

    LOOP ON EACH OBJECT IN x AS xi
        IS min_x INITIALIZED?
        THEN
            IS xi SMALLER THAN min_x?
            THEN SET min_x AS xi
        ELSE SET min_x AS xi
    CONTINUE LOOP

    IS min_x INITIALIZED?
    THEN RETURN min_x
    ELSE EXIT WITH ERROR
END FUNCTION
```

As a good programming practice, always return something from your functions, be it either the result or an error (or error code).